# REDSHIFT - Permissions needed to see all users queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-redshift

Im querying redshift to get the last queries that were sent. But it just shows the queries I executed, I checked the amount of users (see query below) and just show my user. How/ what permissions should I need to get all the queries instead of just mines?

`select userid from stl_query group by 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a superuser to see the queries of other users.  see - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html